# Code Coverage: How to write 100% coverage tests in pytest for functions having except KeyboardInterrupt blocks?

Tags: python, exception, pytest, code-coverage, keyboardinterrupt

I have a function which catches KeyboardInterrupts for additional functionalities and I have to write tests in pytest and I don't know how to create a testcase to cover the KeyboardInterrupt catch block.

The code is similar to this:

```
# main_game.py
class Cache:
    other_details = dict()

def save_progress_for_future(progress):
    file = open('progress.json', 'w')
    content = {'progress_percent':progress, **other_details}
    json.dump(content, file)
    file.close()

def loadingBar():
    progress = 0
    while True:
        try:
            ...  # other stuff
            progress = get_progress_percent()
            print('\r Loading' + str('.' * progress//10) + '\r', end='')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            save_progress_in_file(progress)
```

How am I going to write tests in pytest in other tests file (say test_main_game.py) to cover the KeyboardInterrupt part, and so that coverage cli tool shows 100% of code coverage in its report?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions like keyboard interrupt signals, out of memory failures and such are generally non-deterministic, so one can't possibly have any guarantees if and when they will be even raised during the normal flow of execution. They originate at OS level rather than interpreter itself (unlike ValueError for instance). Given that, there is no reliable way to simulate those conditions to arise and align properly with the execution of a unit test code.

Now what you can do is to simulate the interrupt somewhere in your **try** block to raise an exception to redirect the execution to the code inside the **except** block. In order to do this, some code in *# other stuff* section or *get_progress_percent()* function should somehow raise the KeyboardInterrupt when under the unit test context.

Since it is unknown what is happening in the *# other stuff*, I'll stick with the *get_progress_percent()*.

For this, a refactoring needs to be applied to a *loadingBar()* to make it accept **a delegate to** *get_progress_percent()* function, like so:

```
def loadingBar(progress_loader = get_progress_percent):
  progress = 0
  while (True):
    try:
      # other stuff
      progress = progress_loader()
      # print to stdout, etc...
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      save_progress_in_file(progress)
```

Now if *loadingBar()* is called without arguments, it will assume the default value of **progress_loader** variable to be your default *get_progress_percent()* function. This is the actual call you make in your program.

To test the alternative flow inside the except block, you might consider to create additional unit test utilizing an overloaded call to *loadingBar()*, passing it the function which raises the KeyboardInterrupt.

Your unit test case might look like this:

```
import unittest

class LoadingBarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def testLoadingBar(self):
    """Test the code in try block"""

    loadingBar()

    # assertions for other stuff
    # also assert that save_progress_in_file() doesn't get called
    
  def testLoadingBarInterrupted(self):
    """Test the code in except block"""

    # mock function to raise the interrupt
    def interrupted_progress_loader():
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()

    # call loadingBar passing it a mock delegate
    loadingBar(interrupted_progress_loader)

    # assert that save_progress_in_file() got called by exception handler

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

So, to wrap it up, some particular edge cases require that your code needs to be adjusted in a way to make it a bit more unit test friendly, which might not a bad thing at all.

I hope this helps

Comment: Good point but when I did almost the same thing in pytest, it captured it and skip all the remaining tests, I think I will have to skip the code coverage for KeyboardInterrupt and its belongings for now. Thanks for the advice. It helped me a lot.